# PyQt UI shows in new window but widgets don't activate signals

Tags: user-interface, pyqt5

I've looked through every thread here I could find, but I haven't seen a question like the one I have.

I have a GUI I created in Qt Designer called app_ui.py (after I pyuic5 it). This is the main application window. I created a new window so the user can adjust some settings. This window is called settings_ui.py. Here's the applicable code in the main application for both:

```
import os
import sys
import glob

from app_ui import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from settings_ui import Ui_Settings

class SettingsWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # Bring in the ui elements
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_Settings()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
    .
    . (application logic here)
    .
    

class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # Bring in the ui elements
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle(f"{self.windowTitle()} ** Version: {__version__} **")
        self.ui.actionSettings.triggered.connect(self.showSettings)
    .
    . (application logic here)
    .
    
    def showSettings(self):
        self.winset = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.displaySettings = Ui_Settings()
        self.displaySettings.setupUi(self.winset)
        self.winset.show()
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ApplicationWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Note: I did use `super(Window_Name, self).__init__()` to initialize my windows in the past, but read somewhere that it's more Pythonic to initialize as `QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)`. I don't know if that's true of not, but both ways work.

When I execute the main application and click on the Settings button, the settings window displays as it should, but none of the application logic works (e.g.: You can press buttons, but the connect events don't fire. The style-sheets don't get applied, etc.).

If I pull out the SettingsWindow class into it's own file with the same `if __name__ == "__main__"` it works as intended.

What am I doing wrong that prevents the Settings Window from working through the main application?

EDIT: Adding minimal reproducible code and making title more descriptive.

Here's the non-working application:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import sys
import glob

from app_ui import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from settings_ui import Ui_Settings

class SettingsWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # Bring in the ui elements
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_Settings()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.btnChange.clicked.connect(self.changeColor)
        self.colorArray = ['black','blue','red','green']
        self.currIndex = 0
        
    def changeColor(self):
        style = f"color: {self.colorArray[self.currIndex]}"
        if self.currIndex < 2:    
            self.currIndex += 1
        else:
            self.currIndex = 0
        self.ui.lblChange.setStyleSheet(style)

class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # Bring in the ui elements
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.btnSettings.clicked.connect(self.showSettings)

    def showSettings(self):
        self.winset = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.displaySettings = Ui_Settings()
        self.displaySettings.setupUi(self.winset)
        self.winset.show()
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ApplicationWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Here's the working standalone SettingsWindow:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import sys
import glob

from app_ui import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from settings_ui import Ui_Settings

class SettingsWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # Bring in the ui elements
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_Settings()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.btnChange.clicked.connect(self.changeColor)
        self.colorArray = ['black','blue','red','green']
        self.currIndex = 0
        
    def changeColor(self):
        style = f"color: {self.colorArray[self.currIndex]}"
        if self.currIndex < 2:    
            self.currIndex += 1
        else:
            self.currIndex = 0
        self.ui.lblChange.setStyleSheet(style)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = SettingsWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Here's the ui.py files

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'settings.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.12.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Settings(object):
    def setupUi(self, Settings):
        Settings.setObjectName("Settings")
        Settings.resize(307, 252)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Settings)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lblChange = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.lblChange.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 251, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.lblChange.setFont(font)
        self.lblChange.setObjectName("lblChange")
        self.btnChange = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnChange.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 120, 121, 24))
        self.btnChange.setObjectName("btnChange")
        Settings.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(Settings)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Settings)

    def retranslateUi(self, Settings):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Settings.setWindowTitle(_translate("Settings", "MainWindow"))
        self.lblChange.setText(_translate("Settings", "This should change colors"))
        self.btnChange.setText(_translate("Settings", "Change Color"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Settings = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_Settings()
    ui.setupUi(Settings)
    Settings.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'app.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.12.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.btnSettings = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnSettings.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 40, 75, 24))
        self.btnSettings.setObjectName("btnSettings")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.btnSettings.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Settings"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Although it's not actually changing any settings, the above code shows the issue I'm having.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Will do @S.Nick. It may take a bit because it's a large application. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Added minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
#import os
import sys
#import glob

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
#from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

#from settings_ui import Ui_Settings
class Ui_Settings(object):
    def setupUi(self, Settings):
        Settings.setObjectName("Settings")
        Settings.resize(307, 252)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Settings)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lblChange = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.lblChange.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 251, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.lblChange.setFont(font)
        self.lblChange.setObjectName("lblChange")
        self.btnChange = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnChange.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 120, 121, 24))
        self.btnChange.setObjectName("btnChange")
        Settings.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(Settings)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Settings)

    def retranslateUi(self, Settings):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Settings.setWindowTitle(_translate("Settings", "MainWindow"))
        self.lblChange.setText(_translate("Settings", "This should change colors"))
        self.btnChange.setText(_translate("Settings", "Change Color"))


#from app_ui import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.btnSettings = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnSettings.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 40, 75, 24))
        self.btnSettings.setObjectName("btnSettings")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.btnSettings.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Settings"))
        

class SettingsWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        
        self.ui = Ui_Settings()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.btnChange.clicked.connect(self.changeColor)
        self.colorArray = ['black', 'blue', 'red', 'green']
        self.currIndex = 0
        
    def changeColor(self):
        style = f"color: {self.colorArray[self.currIndex]}"
        if self.currIndex < 2:    
            self.currIndex += 1
        else:
            self.currIndex = 0
        self.ui.lblChange.setStyleSheet(style)


class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.btnSettings.clicked.connect(self.showSettings)

    def showSettings(self):
#        self.winset = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()                            # ---
#        self.displaySettings = Ui_Settings()                             # ---
#        self.displaySettings.setupUi(self.winset)                        # ---
        self.winset = SettingsWindow()                                    # +++
        self.winset.show()
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ApplicationWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image]

---

**Update**

> This works, but it doesn't even try to answer my question. What am I doing wrong that prevents the Settings Window from working through the main application?
>
> The UI elements have to stay in their own file, I can't combine everything into a single file.

Nothing prevents the settings window from working through the main application.

You have written the logic in the `SettingsWindow` cadass, but nowhere do you instantiate this class to use this logic.

I noted in the code what needs to be removed and what needs to be added. You do not need to create an instance of `self.displaySettings`, since you have already created `self.ui` in the `SettingsWindow` class. You just need to create `self.winset = SettingsWindow ()` and that's it.

You can combine everything into one file or use separate files - this does not change the essence.

**main.py**

```
#import os
import sys
#import glob

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

from settings_ui import Ui_Settings
from app_ui import Ui_MainWindow
        

class SettingsWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        
        self.ui = Ui_Settings()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.btnChange.clicked.connect(self.changeColor)
        self.colorArray = ['black', 'blue', 'red', 'green']
        self.currIndex = 0
        
    def changeColor(self):
        style = f"color: {self.colorArray[self.currIndex]}"
        if self.currIndex < 2:    
            self.currIndex += 1
        else:
            self.currIndex = 0
        self.ui.lblChange.setStyleSheet(style)


class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.btnSettings.clicked.connect(self.showSettings)

    def showSettings(self):
#        self.winset = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()                            # ---
#        self.displaySettings = Ui_Settings()                             # ---
#        self.displaySettings.setupUi(self.winset)                        # ---
        self.winset = SettingsWindow()                                    # +++
        self.winset.show()
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ApplicationWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: This works, but it doesn't even try to answer my question. What am I doing wrong that prevents the Settings Window from working through the main application? The UI elements have to stay in their own file, I can't combine everything into a single file.